# How to make a loading animation play, upon visiting website?

Tags: html, css, video, video.js, autoplay

Basically I have made a website thats meant to look and feel like a mobile app. Everything is in order, except for one thing!

I made a small loading animation, just to further make it feel like it's an actual app, and not a website. I want to make the animation play upon visiting the site, and then transfer to the landing page when the animation is done.

Is there an easy way this can be done?

(The website is made as a wordpress theme, I coded from scratch.)

Comment: It's solved, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   // You animate your element
   jQuery('#your-element').addClass('animate');
   setTimeout(function(){
     window.location = 'http://www.your-new-url.com';
   }, 2000); // You let 2 seconds of animation and then you redirect the user.
});
```

Tell me if it works ! :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't work! I solved the problem tho :) Thanks!

Comment: Ok sorry. Could you please write your answer so people with the same problem could have an answer ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a div with the animation.
then when the animation is finished you make it invisible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("$('#loading').fadeOut(700);", 3000);</script>

<div id="loading">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/JxLFV9e.jpg">
<table width="1000" height="100" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="loadingimg">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RB7FxT1.gif">
        <p>
        Loading Webpage...
        </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<style>
#loading {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding-top: 100px;
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: black;
z-index: 9000;
}
#loadingimg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding-top: 500px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: black;
z-index: 9000;
}
</style
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped, and it's now loading. Only thing is, it keeps going in a loop, instead of going to the website. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @northlyk did you add the javascript code ? <script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("$('#loading').fadeOut(700);", 3000);</script>
This will make it fade after 3 seconds "3000"

Answer (score 0):

You can change loading image time in window.setInterval(checkReady, **3000**)

```js
function onReady(callback) {
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 3000);
    function checkReady() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            callback.call(this);
        }
    }
}
function show(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
}
onReady(function () {
    show('page', true);
    show('loading', false);
});
```

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#page {
    display: none;
}
#loading {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5);
    background-image: url("https://loading.io/spinners/hourglass/lg.sandglass-time-loading-gif.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
     <h1 align="center">Welcome to My Page</h1>
</div>
<div id="loading"></div>
```